# What can trigger a UITableView reload?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm chasing this weird bug where my `UITableView` (which is backed by a `NSFetchedResultsController`) is being reloaded without me explicit asking for it. This UITableView has a `UITableViewController` as it's controller and a View Model as it's Data Source. The flow works as it follows:

1. Click the filter button
2. Filter screen appears
3. Select one filter
4. Click Filter button
5. `tableView` from `presentingViewController` is reloaded
6. Filter screen disappears

Now I know, some things can trigger the reload in this scenario:

- A call to any of the reload functions (row/section)
- `NSFetchedResultsController` delegate being called

None of these are true. The only thing that happens is the dismissal of the Filter List Screen - which is triggered by the Filter button:

```
@IBAction func filterButtonAction(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.presentingViewController!.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
    }
```

Note that the `UITableView` reloading is only happening after calling `filterButtonAction`, not before. This indicates that's something related to `UIViewController`'s callbacks (`viewWillAppear` etc), but there's not a single reloadTable to be found (and I don't even implement `viewWillAppear` on the `presentingViewController`).

What could be triggering the `tableView` reload here? Is there a way to trace a call to the `tableView` data source?

Comment: Chceck if you are not messing with tables data source in viewWillAppear etc. that might do it I think

Comment: It seems like tableView is reloaded after viewWillAppear is called but just before viewDidAppear of a view is called. But that happens only if tableView is added as a subview to the parentView. Which seems like tableView is listening to its parentView's life cycle. You can remove the tableView from its superview and add it back when ever you think its ready for reloading. But I don't understand why you would find the initial reload of a tableView hampering your logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is an iOS 8 issue - I started testing in an iOS 7 device, and reloadTable wasn't called at random.

Comment: Will create a rdar about it.